# Speeding up web search in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, rvest

I have a list of 5500 latin names for species that I want to find the common names for. To do this I am running a loop which searches wikipedia for the latin name and then scrapes the common name from the resulting web page.

Heres the code:

```
names <- vector()
for (i in binomial){
  session <- html_session('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
  form <- html_form(session)[[1]] %>%
    set_values(search = i)
  submitted <- submit_form(session, form)
  name <- submitted %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="firstHeading"]') %>%
    html_text()
  names <- append(names, name)
}
```

Where binomial is the list of latin names.

This is a very time consuming process is there any way to optimise this code to speed it up?

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend to SLOW it down! Wikipedia will likely block your IP if you do 5500 queries too fast!

Comment: @Jite I hadn't thought of that! Surely they wouldn't think it was a DDoS attack or something?

Comment: Check out Wikipedia’s guidelines for web scraping (e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt), they’re probably not happy about such usage. Use a dedicated web API instead. Whether and where such a web API exists probably needs some researching though (cursory search reveals https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php). Or check out Wikipedia’s data dump downloads.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I had not thought about things like this, I'll do a bit of research. Thank you for making me aware of this.

Comment: you should work with that I think: https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/wikimedia.org/dumps/10wikipedia/20101026/